# Installing pip packages from bat file and OSGEO Shell?

Tags: pyqgis, osgeo4w, bat, pip

After installing QGIS (that from the 2.14 version has `pip` installed by default) I want to automatically install some pip packages within a bat file.

One method to do that is writing a `file.txt` with all the needed packages, open the OSGEO Shell **as admin**, cd in the directory of the `file.txt` and launch `python -m pip -r file.txt`

How do I make a bat file that automatically runs the Shell ad admin without asking for the password (that is the same behavior of right click and run as administrator)?

Comment: Is this OSGeo Shell specific? Otherwise I think stackoverflow might be more appropriate

Comment: actually I'd like to do it with the OSGeo Shell yes.. Should I move the question anyway?

Answer (score 1):

If the only problem is running a program with administrator privileges, then yes you can do it. There are many guides on the web, on "how-to run shortcuts with admin rights", and each of those guides have 1 thing in common. You enter the password once, and when the shortcut is ran again, the password prompt shouldn't appear. I used the [guide found here](http://news.softpedia.com/news/run-apps-as-admin-without-password-prompt-from-standard-windows-accounts-494677.shtml).

When you create a new shortcut, a new prompt should appear, which will ask for the user-info/application path:

```
runas /user:computer_name\Administrator /savecred “C:\your_script_path\script.bat”
```

Now the /savecred should save the password, making the next shortcut run password free while being ran with administrator privileges.

I assumed that you are using a windows OS. If you are on a Unix based OS, I will reform my answer.